# Ant, (over)write into a file

Tags: file, scripting, ant

How to write (or overwrite) the following contents:

```
            <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>ged.eprom</groupId>
                <artifactId>epromx</artifactId>
                <version>${version.to.set}</version>
                <classifier>stubjava</classifier>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
```

into file called pom.xml in the current directory.

I have tried the ant script:

```
        <echo file="pom.xml">
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>ged.eprom</groupId>
                <artifactId>epromx</artifactId>
                <version>${version.to.set}</version>
                <classifier>stubjava</classifier>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </echo>
```

But I obtained the error message:

```
echo doesn't support the nested "dependencies" element.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ant parser is reading the data that you want to echo as an attempt to add invalid child elements to an `<echo/>` parent.  If you would like to echo that info out to `pom.xml`, you should use the `&lt;` and `&gt;` entities to encode your element output:

```
<echo file="pom.xml">
            &lt;dependencies&gt;
                    &lt;dependency&gt;
                            &lt;groupId&gt;ged.eprom&lt;/groupId&gt;
                            &lt;artifactId&gt;epromx&lt;/artifactId&gt;
                            &lt;version&gt;${version.to.set}&lt;/version&gt;
                            &lt;classifier&gt;stubjava&lt;/classifier&gt;
                    &lt;/dependency&gt;
            &lt;/dependencies&gt;
</echo>
```

Answer (score 24):

You must escape the content with a CDATA tag, that also means that it won't interpret the variable substitution, so I would break it up in three echo statements.

```
    <echo file="pom.xml"><![CDATA[
            <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                            <groupId>ged.eprom</groupId>
                            <artifactId>epromx</artifactId>
                            <version>]]></echo>
    <echo file="pom.xml" append="true">${version.to.set}</echo>
    <echo file="pom.xml" append="true"><![CDATA[</version>
                            <classifier>stubjava</classifier>
                    </dependency>
            </dependencies>
   ]]> </echo>
```

Comment: Good catch on the ${} substitution

Comment: Note that Ant has expanded properties in CDATA blocks since 1.8.0. You can use `expandProperties` attribute on `replacetoken` to control that behavior.

Answer (score 13):

You have the `echoxml` task:

http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/echoxml.html

```
<echoxml file="pom.xml">
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>ged.eprom</groupId>
      <artifactId>epromx</artifactId>
      <version>${version.to.set}</version>
      <classifier>stubjava</classifier>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</echoxml>
```

Comment: Although it does not matter to this particular XML snippet, it should be noted that the `echoxml` task does not necessarily write the XML you give it verbatim.  For example, at least when using Ant 1.8.2 on Windows (and likely other versions on other platforms), using the `echoxml` task seems to switch the order of any attribute nodes I include to be sorted alphabetically:

    `<echoxml file="blah.xml">
        <el b="x" a="x" />
    </echoxml>`

will be written out with the attribute order switched to alphabetical, i.e.
    `<el a="x" b="x" />`